# Adding fragments to display a full screen layout

Tags: android

I want to use fragments to display the Now playing screen whenever a user clicks on a song.I am having a main_activity layout that displays the list of songs and a item click listener.Now i want to open another layout which completely occupies the screen showing the current song that is being played.I think i can achieve this using a fragment but can't find a way to implement it.

Here is my main_activity xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>``
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now i want to replace this entire layout with now playing layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

your main_activity.xml should be like this :

```
  <FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_frame"

android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  >

<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:context=".MainActivity"
 tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"/>``
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

on button click you have perform this code :

```
  Fragment fragment = new NowPlayingFragment();


 ((FragmentActivity) view.getContext()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

so this will replace a fragment on your current activity

EDIT:
Here is my fragment class

```
public class NowPlayingFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

public NowPlayingFragment() {
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_playing, container, false);
}
```

Comment: having you changed your mail activity xml

Comment: yes i did exactly what you suggested but it doe not work. First i thought that my recycler view listener has some problem so To make matter more simply i simply added a button in my main activity and then set an on click listener on it and calling the fragment transaction manager but still nothing happens. Most likely my layout is not getting replaced hope to find a solution soon.

Comment: I found the solution the layout was not getting replaced because i wasn't using '@Override' notation in my fragment class.